# If $E|Y|\lt \infty$, $E[Y|X] = m(X)$ and $(X_1,Y_1)$ come from same distribution as $(X,Y)$. Is it true that $E[Y_1|X_1] = m(X_1)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

If $X,Y$ are random variables, such that $\mathbb E|Y|\lt \infty$, $\mathbb E[Y|X] = m(X)$ where $m$ is some Borel measurable function and $(X_1,Y_1)$ come from same distribution as $(X,Y)$. Is it true that $\mathbb E[Y_1|X_1] = m(X_1)$?

**Attempt**
I managed to prove
$$\mathbb E[Y_1] = \mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|X]] = \mathbb E[m(X)] = \mathbb E[m(X_1)]$$
which leads to
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y_1|X_1]] = \mathbb E[m(X_1)],$$
but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $m$ is some Borel measurable function.

Comment: Morally, this must be true, otherwise conditional expectation would depend on the underlying abstract space, making it a not so useful notion. Though admittedly, I’ve never thought about this before, nice question.

Comment: @Speltzu
Its not quite the same question. X and Y from the comments satisfty the relation. $\mathbb E[X|X] = X = id(X)$, $\mathbb E[Y|Y]=  Y = id(Y)$

Comment: You're right. The equality is a simple application of the post I was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true. Let $B$ be a Borel subset of the real line. Then $$\int Y \mathbb 1(X\in B)\,dP = \int y \mathbb 1(x \in B)\,\mu(dx,dy) = \int m(x)\mathbb 1(x\in B)\,\mu(dx,dy)$$
, where $\mu$ is the law of $(X,Y)$ and coincidentally $(X_1,Y_1)$. It follows $$\int m(x)\mathbb 1(x\in B)\,\mu(dx,dy) = \int Y_1 \mathbb 1(X_1\in B)\,d\tilde P$$
, since
$$\int Y_1 \mathbb 1(X_1\in B)\,d\tilde P = \int y\mathbb 1(x\in B)\,\mu(dx,dy)$$